# Exclude email addresses in a separate file

Tags: text-processing

I have a file that contains, among other characters, many hundreds of email addresses.
The email address is always between the characters "=>" and "<=". So

`=>email@example.de<=`

In the text file it looks like this:

```
323168fdsafdafsdfj=>email1@example.de<=askdjfköj4243j40278012
jköjökajsdöfajsdkf2323323j=>email2@example.de<=jököj
```

How can I use text processing to exclude the email address and write it to a new file?

Comment: Try: grep -oP '(?<=\=>)[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}(?=<=)' file.txt > new_file.txt

Comment: I had edited my question. Sorry, there were two mistakes.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work. But still thanks for the help. ​

Comment: Are there multiple occurrences of the pattern `=>...<=` in each single line or only one per line?

Comment: You ask about "excluding" but I wonder if you mean "extracting". Do you want the text without the email addresses in the new file (excluding) or the email addresses without the other text (extracting)?

Comment: (You have already received multiple answers about how to exclude, so probably post a new question if you really meant to extract. But it should be trivial; `grep -oP '(?<==>)[^<>@]+@[^<>@]+(?=<=)' file`

Answer (score 3):

If there are multiple addresses per line, as shown in your example, then I'd suggest using perl - since its regex engine allows non-greedy matches:

```
perl -pe 's/=>.*?<=//g' < file > newfile
```

You could try to synthesize non-greedy matching in sed e.g.

```
sed 's/=>[^=]*<=//g' < file > newfile
```

however this will fail if any of the email addresses contains the `=` character (not sure if the RFC permits that).

With awk, you could make the input field separator a regex that matches and consumes the addresses (this has the same issue with `=` in an address as the sed solution, for the same reason):

```
awk -F '=>[^=]*<=' '{$1=$1} 1' < file > newfile
```

Answer (score 1):

With [`awk`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/awk.1posix.html):

```
awk 'gsub("=>.+<=", "", $0)' file > newfile
```

… that wold delete the first occurrence of `=>` and anything after it (has to be at least one character) up to the last occurrence of `<=` including it in every line. Which might result in deleting portions in between multiple occurrences of `=>...<=` if it happened more than once in the same line … In which case you can change `"=>.+<="` to `"=>[^=]+<="` which will match any character but the character `=` in between each leading `=>` and the following `<=` and that should match and delete each single `=>...<=` pattern individually given there are no `=` characters in between and that’s AFAIK as close as it gets to resemble none-greedy RegEx matching in awk regarding your requirement which by the way is not clear as which of the two cases it is.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
grep -Pio '\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}\b' orig_file.txt > only_mails_in_file.txt
```

Comment: I think OP wants to exclude emails, but this includes emails only and excludes everything else ... Regardless, I think it can be simplified to `grep -Po '(?<=>).*?(?=<=)'`